# Is there a better way to randomize which enemy to spawn?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently making a game where I want to spawn a lot of different enemies. Currently I have a lot Data containers for units I create through ScriptableObjects. These units contain different sorts of data such as HP, loot, damage etc. I've thought of adding another type of data which is going to be their individual % to spawn or something similar but I am kind off stuck not knowing how to implement something like that.

Here is my current code where I spawn enemies completely randomize from two different lists of either Melee or Ranged enemies.

```
IEnumerator SpawnEnemies()
    {
        //Spawn enemies while amount of enemies are under predetermined enemy amount.
        while (spawnedEnemies < totalEnemiesInCurrentWave)
        {
            //Randomize if Melee or Ranged enemy.
            whichEnemyType = Random.Range(0, 2);
            GameObject enemy = waves[currentWave].enemyPrefab[whichEnemyType];

            spawnedEnemies++;
            enemiesInWaveLeft++;

            //Can I get a probability % to spawn each enemy? Currently completely random.
            switch (whichEnemyType)
            {
                case 0:
                    GameObject Melee = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Melee.GetComponent<Melee>().unit = meleeUnits[Random.Range(0, meleeUnits.Count)];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    GameObject Ranged = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Ranged.GetComponent<Ranged>().unit = rangedUnits[Random.Range(0, rangedUnits.Count)];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenEnemies);
        }
        yield return null;

    }
```

Can someone point me to a better way to handle randomizing enemies or if possible, give me some sort of idea in how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: The question is not clear, but if you want to weight the chance of one or the other it is not difficult.  For a 3 in 10 chance, pick a random from 0 to 9.  If the value if the value is 2 or less, use A else B

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp yes that is quite easy to do but can slowly build up to a lot of WET code (code that is repeating). I was looking for ideas that are a bit more DRY (Dont Repreat Yourself).

Comment: I don't have any example code handy, but a better way to do it is to have each spawner accumulate a random number of "tickets" each second, and when the tickets go past 100, spawn it and reset the tickets to 0.   This way, if you give more than zero tickets each time, you can guarantee that at least one will spawn within a given amount of time, and you can also guarantee that they don't spawn too quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't take into account your separate list of ranged and melee units, but you could use this to assign a weight to every enemy's Scriptable Object, and then the enemies that spawn will be based on the weights of all of your enemies.  I recommend just having one list of enemies, rather than having separate lists for melee and ranged enemies.

This code assumes your Scriptable Object is called `Enemy` and you add a `weight` field to it.  If you want your weights to be specific to each wave (instead of each enemy type), then move the `weight` field onto the enemy's prefab instead of its ScriptableObject.

```
IEnumerator SpawnEnemies()
{
    int totalWeight = 0;   
    foreach (var enemy in waves[currentWave].enemyPrefab)
    {
       totalWeight += enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().weight;
    }

    // Spawn enemies while amount of enemies are under predetermined enemy amount.
    while (spawnedEnemies < totalEnemiesInCurrentWave)
    {
        spawnedEnemies++;
        enemiesInWaveLeft++;  // I think you should be decrementing instead of incrementing?

        // Determine which enemy to spawn, based on all enemy weights
        var enemy = GetEnemyToSpawn(totalWeight);
        var spawnedEnemy = Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);

        // Here you'll have to handle adding the enemy to the appropriate
        // "enemies" list

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenEnemies);
    }
    yield return null;
}

// Suppose:
//    enemy A: weight 2
//    enemy B: weight 6
//    enemy C: weight 3
// Then
//    enemy A: 2/11 chance of spawning
//    enemy B: 6/11 chance of spawning
//    enemy C: 3/11 chance of spawning   
private GameObject GetEnemyToSpawn(int totalWeight)
{
    int weight = Random.Range(1, totalWeight);

    foreach (var enemy in waves[currentWave].enemyPrefab)
    {
        if (weight <= enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().weight)
        {
            return enemy;
        }
        weight -= enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something similar to what I was looking for! Thank you very much! Gave me a lot of ideas that I will look into. Should I mark as solved now or wait and see if it helps me or not

Comment: When I'm looking for suggestions rather than a specific answer (like you are), I often leave the question unsolved for a few days to see if I get additional suggestions.  If I were you, I'd leave it unsolved until either you get it working or several days pass with no new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Random.Range((int)0, (int)2)` which only return 0 or 1. Use `Random.Range(0f, 1f)` instead which yields a float between 0 and 1:

```
IEnumerator SpawnEnemies()
{
    const float MeleeSpawnRatio = 0.8f; // assuming a 8:2 ratio between melee/ranged

    //Spawn enemies while amount of enemies are under predetermined enemy amount.
    while (spawnedEnemies < totalEnemiesInCurrentWave)
    {           
        //Randomize if Melee or Ranged enemy.
        whichEnemyType = Random.Range(0f, 1f) >= MeleeSpawnRatio ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Or use Unity's built-in `Random.value`, which returns the same thing (a float between 0 and 1).